# how to check if the textbox int value is greater than datagridview CurrentRow int value

Tags: c#

how to check if the textbox int value is greater than datagridview CurrentRow int value.

```
What I have 

            if (int.Parse(txtAddQty.Text) >= dtgList.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value)
            {
                // Here what I want to do
                
            }
```

but ended with error Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'

anyone with the solution. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain of the Cell's value type

```
if (int.Parse(txtAddQty.Text) >= (int)dtgList.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value)
{
     // Here what I want to do
                
}
```

Otherwise, you'll be safer:

```
string cellValue = dtgList.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
int intValue;
bool isInt = int.TryParse(cellValue, out intValue);
if (int.Parse(txtAddQty.Text) >= intValue && isInt)
{
     // Here what I want to do
                
}
```